# CSS Not Working Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to style an ASP textbox by linking it to my CSS file.
However, the standard textbox remains.
Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" CssClass="tb5"></asp:TextBox>
```

CSS file:

```
.tb5 {
    border:2px solid #456879;
    border-radius:10px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 230px;
}
```

This code is being used off a master page. Is there any other referencing I need to do or anything else missing? Thanks!

Comment: please make sure your css file is loaded

Comment: Is your css file linked into the page?

Comment: try `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" class="tb5"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Is it the css external stylesheet you want to include or the css style class itself?

Comment: can show the code already rendered (html)?

Comment: @ling.s `Cssclass` used for asp controls

Comment: @Radian yes, but class is also used

Comment: The fact is that should work, so starting with the basics. Make sure the `CSS` page is linked in correctly. Then as someone else already said, try refreshing the browser and clearing the cache. This can be done via `shift` + `F5`or `CTRL` + `F5`. The problem should have been caused by one of these reasons. If the problem is still occurring there maybe some conflicting code.

Comment: Its sure that this code works, so if not work for you, probably the browser not found the css file!, or not have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Refresh your browser cache (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+R). Examine your text box in browser with Developer Tools, putting attention to styles.

Comment: Double F5 (chrome), or CTRL + F5 (IE, FF) are other approaches.

Comment: @scheien Sorry what? Double `F5`? That would refresh 2 times. Chrome is `Shift` + `F5`.

Comment: I've experienced that Chrome did not refresh the cache unless I did a double F5. Dunno why, but could be my Chrome that's acting up :) Or some keybindings that are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're loading the CSS file with this style.

Open the browser tools to see if the css file is loading, or not - probably not, and correct that.

Comment: +1 Yes this is probably the issue. This code works and if the style is attached on the page is works, so is not find it on css.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to check by inspect element in Firefox by right click to object page then choose inspect element, then your css rule will appeear.

other step : install phoenix editor extension in your Firefox, it will help you what file .js and .css that loaded in your page.

It usually related with wrong file path to load css file